# Where do InstructionErrors go?

Tags: transactions, error, logs

I have my validator running, I have my logs running, I have a program loaded with many different custom InstructionErrors. I submit a tx, and when it succeeds I see all the log messages. When the tx fails however, the log prints nothing.

Where do the errors go; how do I find them?

Thank you.

Here is what I am using to define custom program errors:

in error.rs,

```
use thiserror::Error;
use solana_program::{
        program_error::ProgramError,
        msg,
};

#[derive(Error, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum ContractError {

    #[error("This is a custom program error")]
    CustomProgramError,
}

impl From<ContractError> for ProgramError {
    fn from(error: ContractError) -> Self {
        msg!("{:?}", error);
        ProgramError::Custom(error as u32)
    }
}
```

Then within instruction.rs

```
use crate::error::error::ContractError::*,

...

if somevalue > othervalue {
    return Err(CustomProgramError.into())
}

...
```

Comment: you're using "log" ambiguously.  can you clarify the instances of validator log output vs transaction log output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @trent.sol yeah absolutely: I am referring to transaction logs, ie those logs that `solana logs --verbose` streams. I am unaware of other log types, and `solana logs --help` doesn't speak to anything more verbose than `--verbose`.

Comment: are you sure the transactions "fail" rather than get dropped?  if the transaction isn't included in a block you won't see its logs anywhere

Comment: @trent.sol I may be using incorrect terminology there. Basically, I know a transaction 'fails' (doesn't work) because I have verified that the program hits a `return Err(ThisIsACustomProgramError.into())`. I am trying to figure out how to recover the returned error to so I don't have to go around commenting code and msg!ing just to figure out that it was a custom program error causing the problem.

Comment: @trent.sol I added the code from my program into the question, just in case I am doing something silly in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found what I was doing wrong. I wasn't handling caught errors correctly on client side. I had to change this from

the wrong way

```
...
} catch {
    console.log(Error)
}
```

to the right way

```
...
} catch(error: any) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: Just a note that while JS thrown objects can be anything (like a string or an array) good errors are actually Errors. 

So you can do `try { ... } catch(thrownObject) { const error = thrownObject as Error; ... }` then proceed assuming that `error` is an `Error`.